# How to read an old SQL Server 2005 mdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, import, mdf

I've upgraded my SQL Server 2005 to 2008, without backing up the databases. I kept the old data folder with the 2 `DB.mdf` and `DB.ldf` files.

So how can I import or read my `.mdf` file into SQL Server 2008 ?

If I try to use the 2008 tools import/export, I am unable to find the source because the 2005 has been replaced. Only the server 2008 is running.

If not possible, An other way, would be to read the `.mdf` file with vb if you know

Thank you for your help

regards
Mike

Comment: Create an empty db and restore the file.

Comment: @FeliceM You can restore from backups, not from the raw data files.

Comment: IIRC, attaching the data files works even if those data files come from an older version, though.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS right click Database folder --> attach then choose your data file and log file accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you attach the SQL 2005 files to an SQL 2008 instance it will know what to do with them (it will upgrade the database). Use [`sp_attach_db`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx), [`CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or even the management tool, [How to: Attach a Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

See [Detaching and Attaching Databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

I recommend make a copy of the files before the attach.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a full article on how to move a Sql 2005 on 2008 sql server.
[Link](http://www.packtpub.com/article/moving-a-database-from-sql-server-2005-to-sql-server-2008-in-three-steps)